# fancyBox autosize IFrame

Tags: c#, javascript, fancybox

So I have an apsx page with 2 buttons at the top and an IFrame below.
The page that displays in the IFrame itself is allowed scroll vertically but what I don't want is a scrollbar on the fancyBox overlay window. 
If I change the height, it's fine but not on different resolutions.

How must I change the default vlaues to account for that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".various").fancybox({
            maxWidth: 800,
            maxHeight: 600,
            fitToView: true,
            width: '70%',
            height: '70%',
            autoSize: false,
            closeClick: false,
            openEffect: 'none',
            closeEffect: 'none'
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the same problem and here is my solution hope so its work for you the same

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("body").css({'overflow':'hidden'});

// on click to show scrollbar
$(button).click(function(){
$("body").css({'overflow':'auto'});
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your general problem is the scrolling bar right?

```
scrolling   : 'no'
```